# Div not vertically centered only in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a div, that has a nested div that contains a UL. The div (nested) is supposed to be centered vertically; however, any trick that I try to get it centered is not working. 
PARENT

```
.splash {
    background: url(../img/splash.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 30%;
    min-height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

CHILD

```
.media {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 3px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us also the HTML code referencing these classes

Answer (score 0):

Vertical centering is pretty straightforward. I like using the `translateY` approach, as shown here within `.media`:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.splash {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/Hxev8VTsTuOJ27thHQdK_DSC_0068.JPG?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 30%;
    min-height: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.media {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 3px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 150%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    padding: .75em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <div class="media">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I added a background color behind `.media` simply for text readability. Also, for the example, I changed the width and height of the parent to `100vw` and `100vh` so that it stretched across the entire viewport. Adding `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)` is what actually accomplishes the centering.

https://jsfiddle.net/0o2kwv2w/